# IllegalStateException: Fragment already added appears if a App was very long in the background

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Hello I am using `fragment` in my android application but I see some strange exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added` appears if a App was very long in the background.

I checked this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61247, [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441932/java-lang-illegalstateexception-fragment-already-added) but how this I can check whether fragment is already added in case when I add the `fragment` in the `FragmentTabHost`

Source Code :

```
public class FirstFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getSherlockActivity());

        mTabHost.setup(getSherlockActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(),
                R.layout.registration);

        // Create Child Tab1
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("child1").setIndicator("Registration"),
                RegistrationFragment.class, null);
    }

}
```

StackTrace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: RegistrationFragment{424d19f8 #0 id=0x7f0600b8 child1 }
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1175)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:616)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:556)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if the fragment already exists before adding :

```
Fragment f = mManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
if(f != null && f instanceof FragmentClassName) {
   //Fragment already exists
} else {
   //Add Fragment
}
```

Comment: Replace FragmentClassName with the name of your FragmentClass.

Comment: see Is it right now http://pastebin.com/xG5WsHxP ?. Is it right that I am adding fragment in tabhost in else part, won't it create any problem later ?

Comment: Nope. As long as the Fragment doesnt exist, it'll add it to the tabhost. Looks good.

Comment: FYI instanceof does a null check

Answer (score -3):

```
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = new FragmentA();
    // if already exists remove it and add again
    if(fragment!= null) {
        manager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
    }
    manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_id, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: Why this should anwser OP question ?

Comment: this answer has nothing to do with the question.