# IllegalStateException: Fragment already added in the tabhost fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-lifecycle, fragment-tab-host

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.loan, PID: 24169
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: FormFragment{428f10c8 #1 id=0x7f050055 form}
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1192)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:722)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1533)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManager.java:489)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:450)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So, I have an android app that build with the tabhost. There are three tabs in total, in the tab2, there is a button to make the fragment transaction in tab2 (which is calling the function in the fragment activity)

```
FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        t.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, mFrag);
        t.addToBackStack(null);
        t.commit();
```

There is exception if I run like this:

1. Inside the tab2, I press the button to change fragment
2. Go to other tab (eg. tab 1 or tab 3)
3. Press back button
4. Throw exception

How to fix that? Thanks for helping

Comment: possible duplicate of [IllegalStateException: Fragment already added appears if a App was very long in the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629080/illegalstateexception-fragment-already-added-appears-if-a-app-was-very-long-in)

Comment: that means the backpress is adding a new fragment , what is the logic in the backstack ? Thanks a lot

Comment: is mFrag is added to some other tab also apart from tab2 ?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

This happens when we try to add same fragment or DialogFragment twice before dismissing,

just call

```
if(mFragment.isAdded())
{
     return; //or return false/true, based on where you are calling from
}
```

Having said that, I don't see any reason why to remove old fragment and add the same fragment again since we can update the UI/data by simply passing parameters to the method inside the fragment

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The accepted answer makes no sense. First, there should be no negation of `isAdded()`. Second, in the comments, it is suggested that this code goes in `onCreate()`, which is also nonsensical. This line of code should be placed directly before the line where the fragment is added (or replaced), not in `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`. It's too late to execute that code in either of those methods.

Comment: `if(fragment.isAdded()) fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);`

Comment: also must be checked for hiding fragments.

Comment: I need to add similar fragments and only attributes in the fragment are different. But duplicated error still occurs.

Comment: i had already implemented to check if fragment already added then return (the code of add fragment will not be executed) , as the my application is live on the play store still i got the crash fragment is already added from the some of the devices not all the devices i am trying to figure it out from the month ago, i can not over come it, i had applied numbers of solutions and update the build on the live play store, still i am receiving the error from the some of the devices like Galaxy S20+ 5G, huawei , there fewer devices that have the issue i got, any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: 一般情况下，用户通过手动点击UI界面，触发的弹框。使用上面的方式是没有问题的。但是有时候，我们会根据设备的一些状态来选择弹框，比如网络的状态，蓝牙的连接状态。这些弹框的时机是无法把控的。可能会存在同一时间内的不同代码片段触发的多次弹框。我们知道commit的操作是异步的。这就导致了这种检查存在问题。比如前一个代码片段执行了commit的操作，在0.01秒后，另一个代码片段执行了检查并添加，此时前一个commit还未执行，导致后一个检查通过，再次添加fragment。此时就会导致重复添加的问题。要解决此类的问题，1.从业务层面避免这种逻辑。2.使用commitNow()。如果是DialogFragment，可以使用showNow()。

Answer (score 17):

Remove the old fragment in case it is still added and then add the new fragment:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment oldFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("fragment_tag");
if (oldFragment != null) {
    fm.beginTransaction().remove(oldFragment).commit();
}
MyFragment newFragment = new MyFragment();
fm.beginTransaction().add(newFragment , "fragment_tag");
```

Comment: shouldn't we send arguments to make any changes to the already displayed fragment? instead of removing and adding it again

Comment: You cannot set the arguments after the fragment was added to the fragment manager. From docs: "This method cannot be called if the fragment is added to a FragmentManager and if isStateSaved() would return true."

So you need to call your fragment methods directly if you want to update UI.

Comment: yes, I didn't mean setting via `setArguments`, was referring to sending arguments as params to update, so removing and adding the same fragment has no use right ?

Comment: It depends. If you need to reconfigure a lot of things it may be easier to just replace the fragment with a new one. It all depends of your needs.

Comment: Is it better to have 2 transactions instead of 1?

Comment: Not really, using a single transaction should work as well.

Comment: I continue receiving the error, if use one transaction. Probably this is due to asynchronous behaviour of work with fragment manager.

Answer (score 11):

You just have to check one condition in your fragment mentioned below:

```
if(!isAdded())
{
    return;
}
```

**isAdded = Return true if the fragment is currently added to its activity.** Taken from the official document.
This will not add that fragment if it is already added

Check below link for a reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()

Comment: thanks for your help, do you mean I put the if(!isAdded()) inside oncreateview?

Comment: Yes, you just have to put that code i have mentioned in my answer above...It means that your fragment is already added in the stack. So, no need to add it again and it returns simply.

Comment: this makes no sense, you cant return void in onCreateView, did you mean onCreate? i tried this in there and it didnt help my issue

Comment: Is this added to `onCreate`?

Comment: Why the negation sign? Shouldn't the fragment be added if !isAdded() ?

Comment: This answer is such a mess

Comment: @Fonix use `onViewCreated(...)` to do the check

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes it happens for not finding proper id from the respective layout. I faced this problem. Then after many hours I found that I set wrong recyclerview id. I change it, and works fine for me.

So, double check your fragment layout.

Comment: Thanks, it was the same for me. The exception message couldn't be more misleading.

Comment: After more than one month for investigating the root cause, This was the reason. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue, and it is absurd that the exception message lead us all here just to find out that the view id was wrong.

Answer (score 8):

You just have to check one condition before start fragment transaction

```
 if (!fragmentOne.isAdded()){
            transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.group,fragmentOne,"Fragment_One");
            transaction.commit();
 }
```

this is working perfactly for me...

Answer (score 2):

Here my solution for Dialog Fragment (you can use this concept also for fragment class)

I have try to click show dialog fragment by tap button multiple time and quickly.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment oldFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("wait_modal");

if(oldFragment != null && oldFragment.isAdded())
    return;

if(oldFragment == null 
    && !please_wait_modal.isAdded() 
    && !please_wait_modal.isVisible()) {
    fm.executePendingTransactions();
    please_wait_modal.show(fm, "wait_modal");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 if (dialogFolderGallery.isAdded()) {
                dialogFolderGallery.dismiss();
            } else { //bla...bla..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this error when not wrapping my body XML inside a ViewGroup inside FrameLayout.

Error:

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".screens.home.HomeEpoxyFragment">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Solved:

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".screens.home.HomeEpoxyFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Hope this may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works like:

```
Fragment oldFragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(READER_VIEW_POPUP);
if (oldFragment != null) {
    manager.beginTransaction().remove(oldFragment).commit();
}

FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
ft.add(this, tag);
ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

It even can occur if in `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` of your `ViewPager` you create an item that already exists:

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    return tabs[0] // Right variant: tabs[position]
}
```

(`private val tabs: List<Fragment>` is a list of fragments in tabs).

Comment: How did you solve this? It's very similar to my use-case

Comment: @Mitch, I wrote `return tabs[position]` in the second line.

Comment: I'm also using the same concept as `return tabs[position]` but it still throws an error

Comment: @Mitch, sorry, I don't know without a code. For general case currently I use https://stackoverflow.com/a/57161814/2914140. Do you think `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` throws the error in `getItem`?

Comment: It's very likely to be the source of the error since it's where the instance(s) of the fragment(s) shown by the `ViewPager` are retrieved

Comment: just posted a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58549379/fragmentpageradapter-throwing-illegalargumentexception-fragment-already-added with my sample code. Kindly take a look at it to gain a better understanding of my situation

Answer (score 0):

To my surprise, I made stupid mistake by calling the fragment transaction twice:

```
if (!FirebaseManager.isClientA && !FirebaseManager.isClientB) {
      fragment = new FragmentA();
      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, null).addToBackStack("").commit();
} else if (FirebaseManager.isClientB) {
      fragment = new FragmentB();
} else {
      fragment = new FragmentC();
}
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, null).addToBackStack("").commit();
```

Make sure you don't make the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Add Fragment as below

```
FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, mFrag);
    t.addToBackStack(null);
    t.commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: What will happen with old and new fragments? Will it replace old with new?

Comment: No, it will not replace it will add the previous fragment to back stack.

Comment: I wonder, is it possible? Yesterday I tried similar code and got an error, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38566628/how-is-the-new-fragmenttransaction-commitnow-working-internally/, because `addToBackStack` is not allowed together with `commitNow`.

Comment: In that link, he is manually disabling the back stack. With addToBackStack it will enable to manage back stack of fragment

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when incorrectly used my ViewModel inside of Fragment like this:

```
//This is wrong!
MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel(getActivity().getApplication());
```

Correct way:

```
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getActivity().getApplication())).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

not good solving, but it work)

***if(!ConfirmDataSync.isVisible) show()***

Answer (score 0):

Fragment transactions are asynchronous.

It is possible that you have two or more calls to this code before the fragment transactions are executed. `!selectPlan04Dialog.isVisible() & !selectPlan04Dialog.isAdded()` condition is `true` and `show()` schedules another fragment transaction to execute later.

Some options for fixing this:

- Create a new dialog every time and don't try to reuse an old one
- Change asynchronous fragment transactions to synchronous with a call to fragment manager `executePendingTransactions()`
- Сall like this

  ```
  videoOptionDialog.show(supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(videoOptionDialog),TrainingVideoMoreOptionDialog.TAG)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `commitNow()` for the transaction. See the docs.

```
/**
     * After a {@link FragmentTransaction} is committed with
     * {@link FragmentTransaction#commit FragmentTransaction.commit()}, it
     * is scheduled to be executed asynchronously on the process's main thread.
     * If you want to immediately executing any such pending operations, you
     * can call this function (only from the main thread) to do so.  Note that
     * all callbacks and other related behavior will be done from within this
     * call, so be careful about where this is called from.
     *
     * <p>If you are committing a single transaction that does not modify the
     * fragment back stack, strongly consider using
     * {@link FragmentTransaction#commitNow()} instead. This can help avoid
     * unwanted side effects when other code in your app has pending committed
     * transactions that expect different timing.</p>
     * <p>
     * This also forces the start of any postponed Transactions where
     * {@link Fragment#postponeEnterTransition()} has been called.
     *
     * @return Returns true if there were any pending transactions to be
     * executed.
     */
```