# Remove fragment from backstack in nested fragments android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a MainActivity in which I have Added a Fragment ==> BenefitsFragment
in BenefintsFragment there is a RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/benefitContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </RelativeLayout>
```

I am adding another fragment like

```
   browseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    RelativeLayout mLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.benefitContainer);
                    mLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.benefitContainer, new ConfirmPinFragment()).commitNow();
                }
            });
```

In my new `ConfirmPinFragment` I am trying to go back to old `BenefitsFragment` as

```
    backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }
            });
```

However this `popBackStack` not working, if i try to remove using

```
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(ConfirmPinFragment.this).commitNow();
```

It crashes saying

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add to the back state from the FragmentTransaction and remove from the backstack using FragmentManager pop methods:

```
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
trans.remove(myFrag);
trans.commit();
manager.popBackStack();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you need to do for this to work. But first of all there is really no need for `commitNow()`. The first thing you need to do is to add the fragment you want to go back to into the back stack during the transaction:

```
browseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            RelativeLayout mLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.benefitContainer);
            mLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.benefitContainer, new ConfirmPinFragment())
                    .addToBackStack("benefits fragment").commit();
        }
    });
```

and when you go back use the `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getChildFragmentManager()` because you actually want the fragment manager that holds this fragment. Child fragment manager is the manager that manages the fragments inside this fragment.

```
backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when using `commitNow()`, the fragment that you add won't be added into backstack. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38566628/how-is-the-new-fragmenttransaction-commitnow-working-internally/41051627#41051627) and [this blog post](http://nikoyuwono.com/2016/12/13/fragment-transaction-commitnow//#read-more) for more info.

If you want to use backstack you should use `commit()` with `addToBackStack()` instead of `commitNow()`

The main reason why `commitNow()` is not adding into backstack is commitNow() will execute the transaction synchronously, if it'll added into backstack the transaction can broke the backstack order if there are another pending asynchronous transactions.

Comment: i have tried both commit and commitNow nothing works

Comment: You need to call addToBackStack() too

Answer (score 0):

**Using Kotlin and  fragment-ktx** using this one:

In your gradle:

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$androidXFragmentKtxVersion"
```

In your Fragment

```
childFragmentManager
      .findFragmentByTag(YOUR_TAG)?.let { fragment ->
        childFragmentManager.commit(allowStateLoss = true) {
          remove(fragment)
        }
      }
```

If you are not using **childFragmentManager** use **requireActivity().supportFragmentManage**r instead

```
requireActivity().supportFragmentManage
          .findFragmentByTag(YOUR_TAG)?.let { fragment ->
            requireActivity().supportFragmentManage.commit(allowStateLoss = true) {
              remove(fragment)
            }
      }
```